# Cisco router with 3 spaces between `deny` and `icmp`

Tags: cisco-ios, cisco-commands

I was configuring `deny icmp any any` traffic when I realized it was not in the config.

I verified it with `do sh run | i deny icmp` command as follows:

```
R1#configure terminal 
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
R1(config)#

R1(config)#ip access-list extended 100 
R1(config-ext-nacl)#deny icmp any any 
R1(config-ext-nacl)#exit 
R1(config)#
```

For unknown reason, there are 3 spaces between `deny` and `icmp` and caused `do sh run | i deny icmp` command to fail.

```
R1(config)#do sh run | i deny icmp
R1(config)#
```

It turns out the config is actually there with 3 spaces between `deny` and `icmp`.

```
R1(config)#do sh run | i deny
access-list 100 deny   icmp any any
R1(config)#
```

What was the reason for this behavior?

Is this normal?

Comment: I feel I should point out, blocking all ICMP will subtly break IPv4. I've seen firewall admins do this and then they're stumped when oddities start surfacing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's normal.  It's just a "quirk" of how the configuration is formatted for display.

Comment: *show access-lists* doesn't exhibit this oddity.

Comment: Looking at the actual code (binary), for some odd reason it's "permit[space]" and "deny[space][space][space]" when the configuration is generated. They don't make any attempt to align the output anywhere else, 'tho. (It would be an interesting bit of trivia for someone in Cisco to search the src repo to see who originally committed that decades ago.)